# access resources from library cause runtime crash

Tags: android, android-library

I had a project and I convert it to module library, and used it inside my main project

the project use butterknife binding library

every thing was working fine , and there is compilation issues, and once the app run on my device I start getting the following crash in runtime

```
2019-05-01 19:03:21.760 29300-29300/com.sbs16.ensofia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sbs16.ensofia, PID: 29300
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class im.vector.view.HomeSectionView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class im.vector.view.HomeSectionView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at com.sbs16.ensofia.base.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:28)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0e00b0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:202)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2968)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1984)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:425)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:22188)
        at im.vector.view.HomeSectionView.setup(HomeSectionView.java:109)
        at im.vector.view.HomeSectionView.<init>(HomeSectionView.java:79)
```

I can access all resources in the code, but I do not know why when I use it it cause this crash

can anyone help please ?

Comment: Create an on-site [mre]

Comment: @Amira I'm facing same issue on fragment. If you're solved this issue please help me.